# Not able to understand why "ajp-nio-8009-exec-XX" thread blocks/ time_waits on AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I am not able to figure out why a couple of threads of type "ajp-nio-8009-exec-XX" get block. A typical thread dump stack trace looks like:

```
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

To start with, my application is not tuned and have the basic configurations. For ex: the server.xml config for ajp-nio connector looks like:

```
  <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

We have multiple webapps running in single tomcat instance and there are multiple re-deployments going on. After a certain amount of time, one of the webapp suddenly starts degrading its performance. (There is absolutely no activity on any of the other webapps running ever! But still I can't stop/ remove them.)

I have attached two thread dumps. In that, Thread_dump_1 we can see "ajp-nio-8009-exec-XX" (XX= 1,10,11,13,14,19,20,6,7,9) are waiting to acquire a certain lock.

In the next dump (Thread_dump_2), we can see that, thread numbered 11 has been progressed by acquiring the lock. In fact, the time difference between thread_dump_1 and Thread_dump_2 must be more than 2-3 minutes. I am not able to figure out what is happening? I have read a lot of blogs/ answers etc but not able to figure out what is happening in my case. I just need a pointer on how should I debug this issue further? What care should be taken and what are the areas that I should focus more. From MAT I can see that, there are class-loader leaks.

**Thread dump files:**

[Thread_dump_1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n00mp72dqw1s7gw/threaddump-1520489698601.tdump?dl=0)
[Thread_dump_1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yk2di82mytu9uh/threaddump-1520489682241.tdump?dl=0)

Further details: We have used Log4j (for storing logs to mysql), and a custom library that makes network calls(which are time consuming).

**UPDATE:** From the GC logs I see that, there is a lot of GC activity going on, Heap size reaches to max size and not much of memory is freed after GC. Metaspace is not getting full though....

Answer (score 1):

`ajp-nio-8009-exec-XX` are worker threads of a thread pool. They are not waiting on a lock, but rather on a [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) object. These are IDLE threads simply waiting until a new task is available in the task queue. This is a normal situation - there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ok. Can you see something unusual in my thread-dumps? Then what could be the reason for my application to slow down? You can see there are a lot of threads in Time_waiting state.

Comment: @neerajdorle Synchronous logging to a database might be a problem. I don't see other suspects in the thread dumps.